# Is it possible to have to have two or more language keyboard configurations at same type in a app in android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, multilingual

An app with two input text field, A and B:

- the A, when you touch, show a screen with keyboard in a English layout;
- the B, when you touch, show a screen with keyboard in a Spanish layout;

I know that I can use different keyboard programs for different app in a root env, but using the same keyboard program with different languages locked for specific fields in the same app, without the need to change manually the input language I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Absolutely this is possible

Comment: I believe it's not possbile. Keyboard is another app and you can't just say it to change language. Even if it's possible for one keyboard app it can be impossible for another one.